How to use keys/values in dictionary from JSON, when neither key or value is known?
Good afternoon!
I am attempting to write a script where some configurations can be made on machines, based on a JSON file passed into it.  The JSON file is loaded into a variable, and that variable is a dictionary.  That dictionary contains other dictionaries and lists of dictionaries.  So my question is, even though I know the structure of the dictionary due to the JSON file, how do I use the keys/values when I don't know what either is going to be?  I only know the structure.
For example:
{
    "Product": "My_Application",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "Locations": [
        {"Atlanta": [
            {"Server_1": [
                {"hostname": "ATLhost1"},
                {"ip_address": "10.10.10.10"},
                {"widget_dir": "/opt/myApp/widget_logs"},
                {"app_type" : "log server"},
                {"log_directories": [
                    {"access_logs: "/opt/myApp/widget_logs/access"},
                    {"error_logs: "/opt/myApp/widget_logs/error"},
                    {"debug_logs: "/opt/myApp/widget_logs/debug"}
                ]}
            ]},
            {"Server_2": [
                {"hostname": "ATLhost2"},
                {"ip_address": "10.10.10.11"},
                {"widget_dir": "/opt/myApp/widget_web"},
                {"app_type" : "web server"}
             ]}
         ]},
         {"Baltimore": [
             {"Server_1": [
                 {"hostname": "BLThost1"},
                 {"ip_address": "10.10.20.10"},
                 {"widget_dir": "/opt/myApp/widget_logs"},
                 {"app_type" : "log_server"},
                 {"log_directories": [
                     {"access_logs: "/opt/myApp/widget_logs/access"},
                     {"error_logs: "/opt/myApp/widget_logs/error"},
                     {"debug_logs: "/opt/myApp/widget_logs/debug"}
            ]},
            {"Server_2": [
                {"hostname": "BLThost2"},
                {"ip_address": "10.10.20.11"},
                {"widget_dir": "/opt/myApp/widget_web"},
                {"app_type" : "web server"}
             ]}
         ]}
      ]
}

Once this is loaded from JSON, how would I access [Locations][0][Baltimore][0][log_directories][0][error_logs] when I don't know that the location name is going to be 'Baltimore'?  Could "Baltimore" be wildcarded somehow?  I am trying desperately to make this script dynamic, so that it can be run on any machine in any location.  In order to do that, however, I have to figure out how to access this data without knowing what some of the data will be.  I definitely do not want end-users having to edit the script in order to be able to run it.
I have attempted to use loops and if statements to accomplish what I need to, but I am ending up with a lot of nested for loops and if/else conditions, which is making readability... suboptimal.  I'm hoping someone smarter than me can suggest a better way, so that someone editing this thing after me will not need a bottle of Excedrin to get through it.
Thank you!

You just take a list of keys at the same level of nesting? Why do you need to know that Baltimore is a possibility beforehand and actively try that key?

how do you know you need baltimore and not atlanta?

You can loop over all the items in the dictionary: for key, value in d.items():

Nothing about this question depends on the dictionary being decoded from a JSON object.

What do you mean by "use"? What needs to happen when the code is run? For example, do you want to see all the keys and values regardless of what they turn out to be? Do you want to find a specific key according to some logic? Or just exactly what?

when someone executes the script, they will enter the hostname for the machine they're running it on.  I have a way to locate that hostname (if it exists) in the loaded data, but then how do I get the other data in that same "server" section.  If set the value of a variable equal to the entire dictionary structure to that point, as noted in my question with all of the square brackets, it works, but I have to specify "Baltimore".  I'm wondering how to get the other values associated with the hostname, without the script "knowing" what that location name is ahead of time.

I apologize for being unclear.  I am not a trained programmer, so I am more or less learning as I go.

@pythonic If you were to step through the logic manually, what exactly would make you pick "Baltimore" over "Atlanta", for example? It seems to me maybe you should parse the JSON, then prompt the user to Select your location from the following:, then display a numbered list of available locations based off what's in your data structure. Then have the user select whichever one is appropriate for them.
